# как присвоить значение в имя переменной в Swift?

Tags: массивы, swift4

Подскажите, как можно решить такую задачу - пользователь вводит список элементов, я его преобразовываю в массив.

```
var arrayItems = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]
```

Затем массив нужно сохранить и присвоить ему название. Таких массивов может быть несколько, поэтому нужно их различать.

```
arrayItems1
arrayItems2
arrayItems3
arrayItems4
arrayItems5
```

Обычно значение присваивается другой переменной. А здесь надо именно создать название новой переменной (любое), а не её значение. Пробовал гуглить, но ничего конкретного не нашел.

Comment: Сохранять куда?

Comment: "VAndrJ просто сохранить данные ввода в переменную типа [String], чтобы можно было потом с ней работать в коде.

Comment: Все-равно не понятно. Мало контекста. Для чего разные переменные? Может достаточно массива?

Comment: @VAndrJ например, это списки сотрудников разных отделов. Нужно с ними работать по всяким разным задачам. Т.е. вначале нужно создать эти списки, а потом выбираешь один из них, вносишь правки, добавляешь, сохраняешь и т.д.